# Contacts list manager

Tags: java

I just learned about arraylists and I got a mission to build Mobile phone application with contact list when you can add \ remove \ modify \ search for contacts.

If you think I should add something to the code feel free to tell me :)

### MobilePhone class

```
public class MobilePhone{

    private String phoneNumber;

    public ArrayList<Contact> myContacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    public MobilePhone(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public void printContactList() {
        if (!myContacts.isEmpty()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < myContacts.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(i + 1 + ". " + "Name: " + myContacts.get(i).getName() + " || Phone number: " + myContacts.get(i).getPhoneNumber());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your contact list is empty!");
        }
    }

    public void addContact(String name, String phoneNumber) {
        if (searchContactByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) == -1) {
            Contact contact = new Contact(name, phoneNumber);
            myContacts.add(contact);
            System.out.println("Contact " + name + " with phone number " + phoneNumber + " just added!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("This contact is already on your list.");
        }
    }
    public void removeContact(String phoneNumber) {
        int index = searchContactByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
        if (index >= 0) {
            System.out.println("You have removed " + myContacts.get(index).getName());
            myContacts.remove(index);
        }
    }

    public int searchContactByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myContacts.size(); i++) {
            if (phoneNumber.equals(myContacts.get(i).getPhoneNumber())) {
                System.out.println(myContacts.get(i).getName() + " Found!");
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int searchContactByName(String name){
        for(int i =0; i<myContacts.size(); i++){
            if(name.equals(myContacts.get(i).getName())) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void changeContact(String oldName, String newName) {
        int index = searchContactByName(oldName);
        if(index >=0){
            Contact updatedContact = new Contact(newName,myContacts.get(index).getPhoneNumber());
            myContacts.set(index,updatedContact);
            System.out.println("You have changed contact " +oldName + " to " + newName + "\n" +
                    "Phone number: " +myContacts.get(index).getPhoneNumber());
        } else {
            System.out.println("No contact named " + oldName + " on your contact list");
        }
    }
}
```

### Contact class

```
public class Contact {

    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public Contact(String name, String phoneNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public String getPhoneNumber(){
        return this.phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

### PrintService class

```
public class PrintService {
    public static void printMenu() {
        System.out.println("Press:" + "\n" +
                        "\r" + "1. Show contact list" + "\n" +
                        "\r" + "2. Add an contact" + "\n" +
                        "\r" + "3. Remove an contact" +"\n" +
                        "\r" + "4. Search for an contact" + "\n" +
                        "\r" + "5. Change info about some contact" +"\n"+
                        "\r" + "6. Exit.");
    }
}
```

### Main class

```
public class Main {
    private static final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static final MobilePhone mobilePhone = new MobilePhone("123456789");

    public static void main(String[] args){

        boolean exitRequested = false;
        while(!exitRequested) {
            PrintService.printMenu();
            int options = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
            switch (options) {
                case 1:
                    mobilePhone.printContactList();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    addContact();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    removeContact();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    searchContact();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    changeContact();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    exitRequested = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    private static void addContact() {
        System.out.println("Name?");
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Phone number:");
        String phoneNumber = sc.nextLine();
        if (phoneNumber.length() != 10) {
            System.out.println("Wrong input!");
        } else {
            mobilePhone.addContact(name, phoneNumber);
        }
    }
    private static void removeContact(){
        System.out.println("Which contact would you like to remove?" +"\n" +
                        "Please type phone number.");
        String phoneNumber = sc.nextLine();
        mobilePhone.removeContact(phoneNumber);
    }

    private static void searchContact(){

        System.out.println("Please enter phone number ");
        String phoneNumber = sc.nextLine();
        if(mobilePhone.searchContactByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) == -1) {
            System.out.println("No contact found with phone number " + phoneNumber);
        } else {
            mobilePhone.searchContactByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
        }
    }

    private static void changeContact(){
        System.out.println("Which contact would you like to modify?");
        String currentName = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your modify");
        String updatedName = sc.nextLine();
        mobilePhone.changeContact(currentName,updatedName);
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just one small note. Do not use the implementation instead of an interface. Instead of `public ArrayList<Contact> myContacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();` use `List<Contact> myContact = new ArrayList<>()`. Also you do not need to repeat the generic type twice, use a diamond operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What I like

You follow the Java Naming conventions and the names you choose for your identifiers are pretty good.

### What I don't like

#### Unnecessary mutability

The member variable `phoneNumber` in your class `MobilePhone` does not change during the objects life time, therefore it should be declared `final`. The same applies to `name` and `phoneNumber` in your class `Contact`.

#### Inappropriate visibility

The member variable `myContacts` in your class `MobilePhone`  is declares `public`. That means that its content can be changed from anywhere outside the class  `MobilePhone`. This violates the *encapsulation/information hiding* principle, one of the most important concepts of *object oriented programming*.

#### Using indexes instead of objects

Your `search*` methods return indexes instead of the real objects. Therefore the caller of that methods must access the list again in case it wants to do something with the data of that particular contact (which is almost always the case...). So you better return the contact object itself.

#### Inline signalling of errors

In case your `search*` method finds nothing you return a *special value*. In Java we have the concept of *Exceptions* to handle this kind of Problem.

Yes, there is a rule, that you should not miss use Exceptions as *control flow*. But they are exactly for this particular purpose, avoiding this *in band signalling* of a *special case* when returning a processing result.

In your small project *Exceptions* will basically replace the `if/else` statements with `try/catch` blocks which does not look like a benefit at all. But in larger projects it is very likely that the *error case* can not be handled by the direct calling method but by some other method way up in the call stack. Then only the code able to deal with that problem needs to know that it may occur. Without the use of exceptions any method way down in the call stack needs this `if` statements.

Another way to go around this is the use of `Optional` as the return value. But that is just another *special value* in my opinion.

#### Naming

As I initially wrote your naming is pretty good, with one minor exception. In your `main` method the local variable `options` will always contain a *single* user choice. Therefore it should not have the plural s.
Having written that, the name `option` might not be that good at all and should rather be `selectedOption` or just `choice`...

---

### Answer to comment

> I've tried before to make all methods (Contact contact) but fo real I got stuck hard. – עמית שוקרון

That should be quite easy.

```
public class MissingContact extends RuntimeException{
   public MissingContact(String message){
      super(message);
   }
}


public Contact searchContactByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    for (contact: myContacts) {
        if (phoneNumber.equals(contact.getPhoneNumber())) {
            System.out.println(contact.getName() + " Found!");
            return contact;
        }
    }
    throw new MissingContact("No contact with number "+phoneNumber);
} // search by name similar
```

To avoid the Exception handling you should apply the *check, then act* pattern by adding appropriate check methods:

```
public boolean hasContactWithPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    for (contact: myContacts) {
        if (phoneNumber.equals(contact.getPhoneNumber())) {
            System.out.println(contact.getName() + " Found!");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
} // searchByName similar
```

Comment: Hi ! thank you for your answer! I've tried before to make all methods (Contact contact) but fo real I got stuck hard. I coudlnt do it alone.. hope someone will guide me to it ;)

Comment: @עמיתשוקרון: see the update, does that help?

Comment: Thank you very much sir, it helped me a lot !

Comment: Hi again! hope you'll see it, should I change only the search method or I need to change every single method to get Contact contact parameter?

Comment: @עמיתשוקרון  Your API should be *consistent* so any method that currently returns an index should return a `Contact` object instead.

Comment: Ok I done! I wish I did it righ should I edit the whole topic or create new one ?

Comment: @עמיתשוקרון it is encouraged to create a new question link to this one from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think Timothy Truckle has covered a lot of good ground here.

I'd disagree with the idea of throwing an unchecked exception when entries can't be found, however.

This exercise has very similar characteristics to the java.util.Map interface (in fact, if the OP wasn't specifically focussing on learning ArrayLists, a Map would be a better structure with which to implement a contact list).

Following the example of Map, if entries can't be found then simply return null.

I'd be inclined to make the Contact class a nested class in MobilePhone, as I don't believe it's needed elsewhere, and I think it needs a good toString() method.

I'm worried by the changeContact() operation - the MobilePhone.addContact() method only enforces unique phone numbers but the changeContact searches by name, so I don't think you're guaranteed to change the name for the contact you might have intended.

I haven't tried to address that problem in the code below (which is untested, so regard it as a sketch of how I'd do this, if forced to use ArrayList for the purpose).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MobilePhone {

  private static class Contact {

    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public Contact(String name, String phoneNumber) {
      this.name = name;
      this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return String.format("Name: %s , || Phone number: %s", name, phoneNumber);
    }
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  private final String myPhoneNumber; // Different name to the contact phone number, for clarity

  private final List<Contact> myContacts = new ArrayList<Contact>(); // use Interface as the field type...

  public MobilePhone(String phoneNumber) {
    myPhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
  }

  public void printContactList() {
    if (!myContacts.isEmpty()) {
      for (Contact contact : myContacts) {
        System.out.println(contact);
      }
    }
    else {
      System.err.println("Your contact list is empty!");
    }
  }

  public void addContact(String name, String phoneNumber) {
    Contact existingContact = searchContactByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    if (existingContact == null) {
      Contact contact = new Contact(name, phoneNumber);
      myContacts.add(contact);
      System.out.format("Contact %s added%n", contact);
    }
    else {
      System.err.format("This phone number is already on your list - %s%n", existingContact);
    }
  }

  public void removeContact(String phoneNumber) {
    Contact existingContact = searchContactByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    if (existingContact != null) {
      myContacts.remove(existingContact); // we're ignoring the boolean result in this case
      System.out.format("You have removed contact - %s%n" + existingContact);
    }
  }

  public Contact searchContactByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    for (Contact contact : myContacts) {
      if (phoneNumber.equals(contact.phoneNumber)) {
        return contact;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  public Contact searchContactByName(String name) {
    for (Contact contact : myContacts) {
      if (name.equals(contact.name)) {
        return contact;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  public void changeContact(String oldName, String newName) {
    Contact existingContact = searchContactByName(oldName);
    if (existingContact != null) {
      existingContact.name = newName;
      System.out.format("You have changed contact %s to %s%nPhone number: %s%n", oldName, newName, existingContact.phoneNumber);
    }
    else {
      System.err.format("No contact named %s on your contact list%n", oldName);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to ask - is there any chance of concurrent use of the MobilePhone class? If so, synchronization needs to be considered...